# How to connect a router and wall ethernet ports together in a new flat

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, switch

I have 4 ethernet ports on the walls in my new flat. The cables of the ports go to a box which is placed above the entrance door (on the inside, of course).

I am currently waiting for the optic internet connection to be installed to my flat. As I've understood, the optic cable will come to the same box and they will put an optic modem there.

I also want to have a router for a wi-fi connection in the rooms. (Note that the modem installed by the specific ISP does not have a wifi option)

My goal is for all devices connected both through the wall ports and wifi to be in the same network so they can communicate between each other just as if they are all connected to the same wifi network. I'd also like for the router to be placed in some of the rooms and connected in one of the 4 wall ports.

Does it make sense for me to put a switch in the box above the door next to the optic modem, with one input and 4 output ethernet ports for the 4 wall cables? With a setup like that, will a device connected in a wall port (eg. Raspberry Pi) be able to communicate with a device which is connected on wifi (eg. another Raspberry Pi) locally?

Answer (score 0):

The ISP might not install a full-blown router for you. Sometimes, they will give you only a bridge - a box which has one port for optical cable and one for UTP cable. This depends on your contract with them.

However, I would try to install the router to the compartment above door and connected all four cables to it. This is the simplest setup possible and, if the box is not metal, the router can also serve as an wi-fi AP. (Or just lay the router on top of it...)

And yes, devices that talk to the same router (be it over UTP or air, or a combination) can talk also to each other.

Comment: Thank you. The ISP installs only a optic modem (that's how they call it, at least) which has a fiber cable input and ethernet cable output. I wanted to avoid placing the router in the box as it's not really big and I don't think i can fit all the antennas etc.

Comment: I see. You can, technically, use the setup you described - switch inside the box and router on one of the wall sockets. Just make sure that all devices in the network see the router as their gateway and the router has ISP's gateway configured. There might be few problems to tackle - dhcp addressing and maybe some traffic separation comes to mind. It may not be doable with unmanaged switch.